# how to hide/display field option for user's record in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

below is the code which I am using in my jsp

```
                <option value="" disabled selected>--Select--</option>
                <c:forEach items="${users}" var="user" varStatus="status">
                    <option value="${user.userId}"><c:out
                            value="${user.userName}"></c:out>
                    </option>
                </c:forEach>
                <option value="-1">All</option>
            </select>

<c:forEach items="${expenseList}" var="list" varStatus="status">
                    <tr>                        
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check"
                            value="${list.expenseId}" class="case"></td>
                        <td>${list.itemDescription}</td>
                        <td>${list.amount}</td>
                        <td>${list.expenseDate}</td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
```

so whenever a user selects All option from the dropdown then he will be able to see the records for all the registered user but the checkbox option will only be available against his records and not for other registered user. but if a logged in user is admin then that checkbox option should be available against all the records... So please help me on how to achieve it in spring or spring security

Answer (score 0):

In Your **Controller** preferabbly `LoginController` , you can check for the `Privilege Users` is having !! then set the same attribute in Session

Now in Jsp just check for that attribute lets say (`roleId`)

```
<c:if test="${roleId eq '1'}"> --> 1 is for SuperAdmin
   Show the CheckBox else not 
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's the best Spring-specific approach, but I would consider the following:

1. Add a field/member to expenseList/list, indicating whether the checkbox should be enabled upon selection of "All", including the logic to that says "if entry is 'owned' by user or user is Admin - set as true, otherwise set as false".
2. Change your checkbox to something like: `<input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check" value="${list.expenseId}" class="case" enableOnAll="${list.isEnabledOnAll}">`
3. When the user changes the dropdown selection to "All", loop throught the checkboxes, and enable only whatever is "true".